# Ping на php для оповещения роботов поисковиков

Tags: php, post, поисковые-системы, ping

Подскажите, как написать скрипт на php, чтобы он отсылал на сервера поисковых систем для привлечения ботов на сайт для увеличения индексирования сайта? Собственно, выполнить пинг с пост запросом на rcp сервер скажем yandex. Чтоб Yandex проиндексировал страницу сайта? Есть пример, но 4 строчка ругань идеть!

```
<?php
function file_open($url,$post)
{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        $get_row_urlink = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $get_row_urlink;
}

$xml = <<<EOL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>weblogUpdates.[anchor=http://Мой сайт.ru|Ping pingomatic.com services with PHP]ping[/anchor]</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>заголовок</value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>http://clubs.ya.ru/company/rss/posts.xml</value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
EOL;

$result = file_open("http://ping.blogs.yandex.ru/RPC2",$xml);
echo $result; // просто для того что бы увидеть ответ сервера
?>
```

Comment: Зарегистрируйте сайт в [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) и [Яндекс.Вебмастер](https://webmaster.yandex.ru/), настройте файл sitemap.xml и желательно robots.txt. Ничего пинговать не надо, никакой код писать тоже не надо. Поисковики сами решат, когда индексировать ваш сайт. Где вы вообще про это прочитали?

Comment: Я не читал Это есть WP !

Comment: Есть программы которые пингуют сервера RPC и серверов достаточно много около 500 штук. А WP это есть плагин ! Да они заходят но не так быстро как хотелось ! Программа PingExpert вроде так название ! Вы хотите расширить свои познания ? Не знали что такое есть ? Я не это сюда пришел обсуждать а именно этот код ?!

Comment: `ругань идеть!` - какая ругань? Можно привести текст ошибки, возможно у вас нет cURL в php

Comment: @Crantisz не возможно, а точно нет.

Comment: $ch = curl_init(); Да кстати прошу простить скорей всего это ! Я заматалса и действительно попутал с другим доменом ! Простите нет Curl

Comment: Господа есть еще такой вариант ! <?php
$urls = file ("urls.txt");
for ($x=0;$x<count($urls);$x++)
{
$url = trim ($urls[$x]);
if (eregi("Thanks for the ping.", file_get_contents("http://blogsearch.google.com/ping?url=".$url)))
{
echo $url." - added\r\n";
} else {
echo $url." - not added\r\n";
}
}
?>

Comment: Ругается : Warning: file(urls.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/virtwww/w_мой домен-ru_e2f6bc1e/http/rpc/RPC.php on line 11 Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/virtwww/w_мой домен-ru_e2f6bc1e/http/rpc/RPC.php on line 15 Warning: file_get_contents(http://blogsearch.google.com/ping?url=): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/virtwww/w_мойдомен-ru_e2f6bc1e/http/rpc/RPC.php on line 15 - not added

Comment: Помогите разобраться ? Очень надо !

Comment: @Helpsetup помог этот способ? поисковики начали индексировать сайт быстрее? какое количество постов отправлял в день в среднем?